# Kendo UI pass additional parameter when create, update and delete

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

When doing a create, update or delete, I need to save other form and get a `id` of that save function and pass that `id` as a additional parameter with these events `create, update, delete`

How can

I have my grid script as below

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                    var crudServiceBaseUrl = "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service",
                        dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                            transport: {
                                read:  {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
                                },
                                update: {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Update",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
                                },
                                destroy: {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Destroy",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
                                },
                                create: {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Create",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
                                },
                                parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                                        return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            batch: true,
                            pageSize: 20,
                            schema: {
                                model: {
                                    id: "ProductID",
                                    fields: {
                                        ProductID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                                        ProductName: { validation: { required: true } },
                                        UnitPrice: { type: "number", validation: { required: true, min: 1} },
                                        Discontinued: { type: "boolean" },
                                        UnitsInStock: { type: "number", validation: { min: 0, required: true } }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: dataSource,
                        pageable: true,
                        height: 550,
                        toolbar: ["create"],
                        columns: [
                            { field:"ProductName", title: "Product Name" },
                            { field: "UnitPrice", title:"Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: "120px" },
                            { field: "UnitsInStock", title:"Units In Stock", width: "120px" },
                            { field: "Discontinued", width: "120px" },
                            { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "250px" }],
                        editable: "popup"
                    });
                });
```

I found something [here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-pass-additional-data-to-create-update-destroy-action-method) but this doesn't look right

I need to post it to

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Add(Product product, int categoryId)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simply inside `parameterMap` change return statement to this so that it would return categoryId

```
return kendo.stringify({
    models: options.models, 
    categoryId: categoryIdFromSomewhere
)};
```

Small note, I use `JSON.stringify`, but quite surte if that will make any difference.

Comment: Can I stop the event if categoryIdFromSomewhere returns 0 or throws error?

Comment: Sorry, have never actually tried that... but you can always check that before click event